# Create a function $f(x)$ defined on $[1,2]$ such that $f(1)=-1$ and $f(2)=1$. $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ must exist for all $a\in [1,2]$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

To add the post title, $f(x)\neq 0$ for any $x\in [1,2]$.

So in my brainstorming, I thought of the piecewise, $f(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$ for $1\leq x <2$ and $\frac{x}{2}$ for $x=2$.

However, I realize that if I did that, the limit would not exist at 2 which doesn't satisfy all the requirements of the problem.

What is a function that would satisfy the $f(1)$,$f(2)$ and the limit requirements and how exactly would you arrive at it?

Comment: You have two points. Could you not start by trying a line?

Comment: That's a good idea. I wouldn't be allowed to just exclude the x-value for the zero though would I? because that wouldn't be for any $x \in [1,2]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint #1

> A function is continuous at $x=a$ if $f(a) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$.

Hint #2

> A function can have a defined limit $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) =L$, but fail to be continuous if $f(a) \neq L$.

Hint #3

> Let's make $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = 0$, but $f(c) \neq 0$.

Hint #4

> The following $f$ works: $f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 2x -3 & x \neq 3/2 \\ 26 & x=3/2  \end{array}    \right.$

Comment: saying $f(3/2)=26$ was so obvious i couldn't even think to do it. Thanks!

Comment: =) Sometimes the obvious answer is best--we know that if $f$ is continuous, then there exists $c$ such that $f(c) =0$ by the intermediate value theorem. Just need to make $f$ not continuous and skip one value =)

Answer (score 0):

If the function does not oscillate nor goes to infinity, then $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exist for any $a$. The function may be discontinuous, but that is not a requirement. In fact it can't be continuous, or it would take the value $0$ by Bolzano's theorem. So there are a lot of options for the values between $1$ and $2$. For simplicity, any nonzero  constant value for $f$ in the open interval $(1,2)$ will work.